# Bucles for anidados en Python

Tags: python

buenas tardes, hace poco empezé a aprender Python y me cuesta entender los bucles anidados. No termino de entender lo que está haciendo el bucle for anidado en este programa.

```
'''
 Definir una función superposicion() que tome dos listas y devuelva True si tienen al menos 1
 miembro en común o devuelva False de lo contrario. Escribir la función usando el bucle for
 anidado.
'''

def superposicion (list1, list2):
    for item in list1:
        for item2 in list2:
            if item == item2:
                return True
    return False

list1 = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
list2 = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'o']
print(superposicion(list1, list2))
```

Comment: Que hace el primer bucle?

Comment: La variable item está iterando sobre la lista1

Comment: ok.. que hace el segundo bucle...

Comment: La variable item2 está recorriendo los elementos de list2 y dentro del bucle hay una estructura selectiva del tipo if que evalúa si la variable item es exactamente igual a item2, si son iguales retorna True.

Comment: perfecto, entonces entendiste a la perfeccion lo que esta pasando. cual es la duda?

Comment: No terminaba de entender el flujo del programa pero ya está. Gracias

Comment: Cuando tenemos bucles anidados, el bucle interior recorre todas sus posiciones antes de liberarse y iniciar la siguiente ronda del bucle exterior. En otras palabras el bucle principal marcara las veces que se repetirá desde 0 el bucle interno.

Te recomiendo mirar algún tutorial básico o directamente a la documentación oficial. Igualmente un for es una estructura básica que funciona igual en python, bash, C o js...

Comment: O sea el primer for va a tomar el primer el elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el segundo elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el tercer elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el cuarto elemento de list1- el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el último elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 y si encuentra que un elemento de la primera lista es igual a un elemento de la segunda lista devuelve True.

Comment: ¿Así funciona??

Answer (score 2):

mira por lo que entiendo la función cicla por todos los objetos de las listas y si el objeto actual es igual al objeto actual de la otra lista devuelve `True` si se termina el bucle y no hubo ningún objeto igual devuelve `False`

```
def superposicion (list1, list2): # Toma dos listas
    for item in list1: # Cicla por los objetos de la lista 1
        for item2 in list2: # Cicla por los objetos de la lista 2
            if item == item2: # Compara el objeto actual del ciclado de la lista 1 con el objeto actual de la lista 2 si son iguales sigue la sentencia
                return True # Devuelve verdadero (que el objeto esta duplicado)
    return False # Se termina el bucle y si no hay ningún objeto duplicado devuelve falso
```

Edit: esto seria util para eliminar objetos duplicados.

Comment: O sea el primer for va a tomar el primer el elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el segundo elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el tercer elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el cuarto elemento de list1- el segundo for itera por todo list2 - el primer for toma el último elemento de list1 - el segundo for itera por todo list2 y si encuentra que un elemento de la primera lista es igual a un elemento de la segunda lista devuelve True. ¿Así funciona?

Comment: si, no se si cuenta como algoritmo pero si que hay un algoritmo que hace algo parecido básicamente cicla por cada objeto y los compara si son iguales los elimina